# Logging In To School Server with Java (HTTPs Url Connection)

Tags: java, android, apache, cookies, https

I am working on a project with a friend to be able to login to our school server and be able to scrape some of webpages without having to use a browser.
We have tried using some of the suggested approaches but have not been able to go pass the redirect to login page.

I realized the following;

A cookie is needed for each session but when I print out the connections's "Set-Cookie" value, I get []-->Meaning there is no cookie.

Could anyone help us to be able to successfully post our credentials and be able to get redirected from the login page to our destinationURL?

Here is our code:

```
    public static void Login() {
    String charset = "ISO-8859-1";//

    try {
        String userid = "useridhere";
        String password = "passwordhere";
        String Submit = "Login";

        String query = String.format("netid=%s&password=%s&Submit=%s", 
                 URLEncoder.encode("netid", charset), 
                 URLEncoder.encode("password", charset),
                 URLEncoder.encode("Submit", charset));

        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        java.net.CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();


        URL url = new URL("url"+"?"+query);

        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        List<String> c = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        System.out.println(c);

        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response)) {
            String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
        }
        response = connection.getInputStream();

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response)) {
            String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error occured");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The value of ``Set-Cookie`` is from the request headers, not from the response's headers.